# How to recreate iPhone's contact list UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I really like iPhone's default contacts list input tables and I would like to re-create an input page similar to them. My v1 app used a bunch of text fields on the screen, but this implementation is better. I have no idea how to do it. Being the newbie, I signed up with http://www.pluralsight-training.net/. However, what I want is more ambitious than what is being taught there. Thanks for any help.

[image: iPhone Contacts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do it but one way could be this one:

- UIScrollView

  - IUImageView (profile pic)
  - UITableView (personal infos)
  - UITableView (all other infos)

You set both UITableView to UITableViewStyleGrouped and you play with the UITableViewCellStyle. A few hours and you should be done.

Good luck.